# JQuery - dynamically selecting inputs with "nth"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a question that I've been stuck on. I have a form and want to dynamically be able to call upon the n-th set of input fields in a form to use them in equations that will output the n-th set of answers. For example "footage2" should be plugged into an equation that will give me "postQuantity2" and then "footage3" should be used to determine "postQuantity3". The problem is that the form can add input areas dynamically so I can't just hard code it to do what I want. Any ideas of how to get the nth set of numbers to be used for an equation and then give me the nth set of answers? If anyone can explain how this would work, or just point out how it wouldn't it'd be very much appreciated! Thanks!

Here is a snippet - http://jsfiddle.net/gv0029/QGW7R/ - to give you a basic idea of what I'm working with and here is some html and js.

HTML

```
<fieldset id="fence">
    <div id="inputFence1" class="clonedInputFence">
        <fieldset id="fenceDescripton">
            <legend><strong>Fence Description</strong>

            </legend>
            <label>Footage:
            <input type="number" id="footage" name="footage" value="" /></label>
            <select name="fenceHeight" id="fenceHeight">
                <option value="select">Select Fence Height</option>
                <option value="6" id="fH6">6 Ft.</option>
                <option value="8" id="fH8">8 Ft.</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset id="post">
            <legend><strong>Post Type</strong>

            </legend>

            <label>Post Quantity:
                <input type="postQuantity" name="postQuantity" id="postQuantity" value="" />
            </label>
            <select name="postMeasurements" id="postMeasurements">
                <option value="select">Select Post Measurements</option>
                <option value="23/8 x .065 x 8" id="23/8 x .065 x 8">2 3/8 x .065 x 8</option>
                <option value="23/8 x .095 x 8" id="23/8 x .095 x 8">23/8 x .095 x 8</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>

    </div>
</fieldset>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="btnAddFence" value="Add Another Fence" />
        <input type="button" id="btnDelFence" value="Remove Fence" />
    </div>
```

JS

```
//Quantity for Posts
    $('#footage, #manualOverrideNo').bind('keypress keydown keyup change', function(){

            var footage = parseFloat($(':input[name="footage"]').val(),10);
            var total = '';

            if(!isNaN(footage)){
                total = Math.ceil(footage /7);
                $(':input[name="postQuantity"]').val(total.toString());
            } else {
                $(':input[name="postQuantity"]').val("");
            }
    });

//Dynamic Fence Input Fields
    $('#btnAddFence').click(function() {
                var num     = $('.clonedInputFence').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                var newNum  = new Number(num + 1);      // the numeric ID of the new input field being added

                // create the new element via clone(), and manipulate it's ID using newNum value
                var newElem = $('#inputFence' + num).clone().attr('id', 'inputFence' + newNum);

                //Fieldset creation
                newElem.find('fieldset').attr('id', 'fence' + newNum);

                //Fence Description 
                newElem.find("select[name=fenceHeight]").attr('id', 'fenceHeight' + newNum).attr('name', 'fenceHeight' + newNum);
                newElem.find(':input[name="footage"]').attr('id', 'footage' + newNum).attr('name', 'footage' + newNum);

                //Post Type
                newElem.find(':input[name="postQuantity"]').attr('id', 'postQuantity' + newNum).attr('name', 'postQuantity' + newNum);
                newElem.find("select[name=postMeasurements]").attr('id', 'postMeasurements' + newNum).attr('name', 'postMeasurements' + newNum);

                // insert the new element after the last "duplicable" input field
                $('#inputFence' + num).after(newElem);

                // enable the "remove" button
                //$('#btnDel').attr('disabled','');
                $('#btnDelFence').removeAttr('disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDelFence').click(function() {
                var num = $('.clonedInputFence').length; // how many "duplicatable" input fields we currently have
                $('#inputFence' + num).remove();     // remove the last element

                // enable the "add" button
                //$('#btnAdd').attr('disabled','');
                $('#btnAddFence').removeAttr('disabled');

                // if only one element remains, disable the "remove" button
                if (num-1 == 1)
                    $('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled','disabled');
            });

            $('#btnDelFence').attr('disabled','disabled');
```

Comment: I think what you're looking for is :nth-child() Selector. Take a look here http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think nth-child will work in this case since there are multiple child elements and the op wants to match them up.

On your footage elements, add a data attribute of, let's say, data-which-pair with a pattern like

id = n data-which-pair = n

$("#footage"+n).click(function(){
  var n = $(this).attr("data-which-pair");
  Do something cool with $("#postQuantity"+n);
}

You might be able to just do a function(n) but I usually follow this longer-winded approach because it is easier to see what's going on. Keep in mind, obviously, that the above is pseudocode that you will need to adapt.

Comment: That sounds perfect. Exactly what I had in mind. Do I need to initalize 'n' in any way or can Ijust plug it in?

Comment: It says that n hasn't been defined. How could I define it as any number?

Comment: Yeah you definitely need to define it. What I often do in this sort of situation is use a data-property on the clickable element - I'll edit the above with that added...